# Postgres/postgis. Find all points so that no two points are within X units of each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a sql table containing approx 46,000 rows of Zipcode and its center lat/lng for cities in the US.

I am wanting to run a query where the resulting set contains a table of points however, all points are at least X units away.  Basically am able to map an area where no two circles (a lat/lng with a radius of X units) intersect.

Comment: Please post your table definition (DDL) and sample data, as txt - **no images**. Also post your expected results from that data and what you have tried. It may be beneficial for you to review [ask].

Comment: Sounds like a job for st_buffer, but please add some more detail to your question. Better still, play with st_buffer beforehand and see if you get anywhere... https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html